# how to remove black top and left outline from inputs

Tags: html, css

```css
.modal{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:9px;
background:lightseagreen;
}

input{
display:block;
outline:none;
border-radius:9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>
<input type='text'>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove black outline top and left of the `input` tag.
I can do this by adding border:
`border:1px solid lightseagreen;`
But I don't want any border or outline arround the inputs, generally, on entire site, because the background color of .`modal` is changable.

Comment: `border: none`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `border: none` in your input CSS

```css
.modal{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:9px;
background:lightseagreen;
}

input{
display:block;
outline:none;
border-radius:9px;
border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>
<input type='text'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `border: none` removes the border completely.

You can just remove the top and left using: `border-left: none` and `border-top: none`.

```css
.modal{
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:9px;
background:lightseagreen;
}

input{
display:block;
outline:none;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
border-radius:9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='modal'>
<input type='text'>
</div>
```